# postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Please help me with the query 
Below are the table and requirement details

[image]

Comment: Please clarify if you want a solution for MySQL or for PostgreSQL. You have tagged the question with both products, but the solutions for each may be different. Your question title says 'postgresql query' but then why tag the question MySQL?

Comment: Post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **windowed functions**

```
select alph_letter, alph_group, min(alph_date) OVER (PARTITION BY alph_group) AS min_date from alphabets;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use the windowing variant of `min`:

```
SELECT letter, group, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
FROM   alphabets
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it :). I've used SQL Server but the syntax should be similar for this problem:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Alphabets') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Alphabets;

CREATE TABLE #Alphabets(Letter VARCHAR(1)
                  , Groups VARCHAR(3)
                  , Dates  DATE);

INSERT INTO #Alphabets
VALUES
      ('A'
     , 'abc'
     , '20161026'),
      ('B'
     , 'abc'
     , '20161027'),
      ('C'
     , 'abc'
     , '20161028'),
      ('D'
     , 'def'
     , '20161101'),
      ('E'
     , 'def'
     , '20161030');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT B.Letter
    , B.Groups
    , MinDates
FROM
      (SELECT MIN(Dates) AS MinDates
           , Groups
       FROM   #Alphabets
       GROUP BY Groups) AS A
      INNER JOIN #Alphabets AS B ON A.Groups = B.Groups;
```

RESULTS:

[image]